# Validation of viewstate MAC failed after using machineKey

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-config

I have a legacy ASP.Net Web forms application using Forms authentication. We had a global error handling routine in place and few times a day, it logs the error "**Validation of viewstate MAC failed.**". I do have  key configured in my web.config which has been generated from a powershell script.

I am running on a shared server without access to IIS services.

Another reason due to which this issue may happen is recycling of IIS. We have ensured that IIS recycles every night to be able to find the root cause of the issue but no luck. Any other reasons that can cause this issue?

Few Links taht i have already gone through and couldn't find any proper answers - [#1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14323699/validation-of-view-state-mac-failed), [#2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38781439/validation-of-viewstate-mac-failed-machinekey-configuration), [#3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27035659/view-state-mac-validation-failed) & [#4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2069786/validation-of-viewstate-mac-failed-view-state-error)

Comment: This link may be helpful https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2915218/resolving-view-state-message-authentication-code-mac-errors

Comment: Thanks, will check :)